# Android TabLayout doesn't change Tab (Fragment) when clicked only works when swiped

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

When I swipe my tabs left or right, the next tab is inflated - fragment is shown properly - however, when I click the tab title,nothing happens . Does this have to be implemented manually? I don't understand swiping works by default, so clicking should as well.

My XML

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tabs" />
```

Main Activity

```
     ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
```

Answer (score 2):

Do it this way:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private final int numOfPages = 4; //viewpager has 4 pages
private final String[] pageTitle = {"Food", "Movie", "Shopping", "Travel"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfPages; i++) {
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(pageTitle[i]));
    }

    //set gravity for tab bar
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
            (getSupportFragmentManager(), numOfPages);

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(onTabSelectedListener(viewPager));
}

private TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener onTabSelectedListener(final ViewPager pager) {
    return new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            pager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    };
}
```

Comment: same thing, tabs only working when swiped, not working when clicked

Answer (score 2):

I ran this problem while updating our app to work on 4.4 devices. Resolved it by calling

```
tabLayout.bringToFront()
```

Answer (score 0):

following code works for me :)

```
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(viewPager));
```